# How to implement automated login without user interaction into azure portal from VSTS using azure CLI & power shell script

Tags: powershell, azure, powerbi, azure-cli

I am trying to import **.pbix** file into azure powerbi workspace collection, for that I used the azure cli and powerbi cli commands.

Power shell script for logging into azure portal and import the **.pbix** file into azure powerbi workspace collection:

```
Param(

#Install npm prerequisites : Azure-cli and Powerbi-cli | Y : N | Optional,  default No
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [bool] $Prerequisites=$false,

# Run the authentication process for the Azure Sub | Y : N | Optional, default No
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [bool] $Authentication=$true,

# Name of the resource group | Ex : "MyResourceGroup" | Mandatory
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $ResourceGroupName,

# Location on Azure for the deployment | Ex : "West US" | Mandatory
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Location,

# Name of the Workspace collection name | Ex : "MyPBIWorkspace" | Mandatory
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $WorkSpaceCollectionName,

# Id of the Power BI Workspace | Ex : "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX" | Mandatory
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string]   $WSguid,

# Path of the PowerBI Report(.pbix) file |    Ex : "E:\Users\PowerShellScriptForPowerBI" | Mandatory
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $ReportsFilePath

)
cls
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "##### Script launched ###### "

if ($prerequisites)
{
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Installing the NPM Packages..."
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Installing Azure-CLI"
$output = npm install azure-cli -g
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "Azure-CLI Installed"
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Installing PowerBI-CLI"
$output = npm install powerbi-cli -g
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "PowerBI-CLI Installed"
}

if ($authentication)
{
  Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Authentication on Azure selected..."
  #azure login
  #$azureAccountName ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  #$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=" -AsPlainText -Force
  #$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
  #Login-AzureRmAccount -C -Credential $psCred
  #Add-AzureRmAccount  -Credential $psCred -TenantId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx' -ServicePrincipal
  #azure login --service-principal -u "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --password "XXXXXXXXXXXxx=" --tenant "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
  azure account set "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  #azure login -u http://myClientEncryptApplication --service-principal --tenant XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "Authentication on Azure done"
 }

 try {

 Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Getting and storing access key..."
 #$CollectionName =$WorkSpaceCollectionName
 $accesKeyPBIJSON = azure powerbi keys list $ResourceGroupName     $WorkSpaceCollectionName --json
 $accesKeyPBIJSON = $accesKeyPBIJSON | ConvertFrom-Json
 $accesKeyPBI = $accesKeyPBIJSON.key1
 Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "Acces Key stored : $accesKeyPBI"

 Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow "Importing the PBIX..."
 $path = $ReportsFilePath +"\Reports\*.pbix" 

 $basename = gi $path | select basename, Name
 $filePath = $ReportsFilePath +"\Reports\" + $basename[0].Name

 $fileName = $basename[0].BaseName

 $output = powerbi import -c $WorkSpaceCollectionName -w $WSguid -k  $accesKeyPBI -n "$fileName" -f "$filePath" 

 Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "PBIX Imported : $fileName"
 Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "###### Script done ######"
 }
 catch {
 Write-Host $Error[0] -ForegroundColor 'Red'
```

}

Whenever I run the above script in local machine it will successfully logged into azure portal but when I check in the code into VSTS, power shell script execution failed in the release definition.

**Error:**

> The subscription 'XXXXXXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX was not found. Please check your spelling, or use the azure login command to set your subscription.
>   error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\buildguest.azure\azure.err

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above error and also tell me how to implement automate login into azure portal from VSTS using power shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error log, please ensure you should login your account firstly, then execute `azure account set "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`. On your local, maybe you had login your account, so, you could execute `azure account set "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` firstly without error log.

If you do this, I suggest you could login your account with service principal. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to create a new service principal.

```
azure login --service-principal -u "displayNamee" -p "password " --tenant "cliet id"
azure account set "*********************"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Walter, the login issue resolved. But I am facing the issue as “npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead”, when I am executing this command npm install powerbi-cli –g. can you please tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: @pradeep Yes, I meet same error log with you. It seems powerbi issue. Sorry I don't work with this, but I try to find the root reason.

Answer (score 0):

For login and selecting a subscription, you can try below.

**ASM**:
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile 
Select-AzureSubscription

**ARM**:
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRMSubscription

Non-interactive logins are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249623/how-to-login-without-prompt)

Comment: The error log is from `azure account set "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` not from PowerShell.