# How to authenticate to Azure REST API using username and password (no App Id)

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, authentication

I need to acquire access token for accessing resources in Azure (https://management.azure.com endpoint) using REST API. Every article a have read, was counting with Appliction Id. In my case, the Azure tenant was just created (programatically) and I have to create some resources in it.

Only thing I have is tenant id, subscription id, user name and password of admin account. How can I authenticate using only information I have? How it works in PowerShell, that does not need to use an Application Id?

Comment: AFAIK, you always need an application. Azure PowerShell is an application too.

Comment: Wondering if you tried using bearer token, az account get-access-token -s <subscription-id> or use user-name and password to get bearer token to call API, example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/operationalize/how-to-manage-access-tokens). The try me on the Azure API pages use bearer token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft PowerShell Application ID to authenticate without having your own Application ID. This code snipet will give you the token:

```
Import-Module MSOnline      # IMPORTANT! Loads type assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext
$TENANTID = ""  # Your Tenant ID
$clientId = "1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894"      # PowerShell Client Id
$MSMgmtURI = "https://management.core.windows.net"
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID"
$redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($MSMgmtURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Always")  
$token = $authResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $token", 'host'="management.azure.com", 'Content-Type' = "application/json"}
```

This is good for getting an access token using the login dialog. I suspect that the Client ID for PowerShell could be used in the Oath2 call above.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my knowledge, it is impossible. As junnas said, even you use user/password authentication, client id is also required.

It is easy for you to create a service principal on Azure, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

After the sp is created, you will get the client id, client secret. You also need give the sp `Owner` role on subscription, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Now, you could use the sp to call rest api in Power Shell, for example.

```
##get token
$TENANTID=""
$APPID=""
$PASSWORD=""
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

##set subscriptionId and resource group name
$subscriptionId=""
$resourcegroupname="shui5"

$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'host'="management.azure.com"
    'contentype'='application/json'
}
$body='{
    "location": "northeurope",
     "tags": {
        "tagname1": "test-tag"
    }
 }'
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/${resourcegroupname}?api-version=2015-01-01"  -Headers $Headers -Method PUT -Body $body
```

Comment: I know how to register app and authenticate using the app. I need to automate the whole process - create tenant (done) and add resources using Resource Manager without any user interaction (trying to resolve).

Comment: @LukášNešpor It is possible, if your account is an Azure AD account. You could login by using non-interactive login. You could check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249623/how-to-login-without-prompt).

Comment: @LukášNešpor Then you could use Power Shell to create a service principal. Check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-5.4.0). Then you could get `tennat id`, `client id`, `client secret`, `subscription id`. Then you could use them to call API.

Comment: Also, you need give the sp `Owner` role on subscription level,  check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-5.4.0#managing-roles).

Comment: But if your account is an Microsoft account, you need create a Azure AD account firstly because Microsoft account does not support non-interactive login. Also, only account and password you could use them to call Azure rest API, `client id` and `client secret` are required.

Comment: I am already using service principal with Owner role. Unfortunatelly it just does not work as expected. Even if the PowerShell cmdlet says that the app is created (gives me app id), it does not exist and using it ends with an error ``AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '{GUID}' was not found in the directory {GUID}``. Sometimes other try helps, but it is not acceptable behavior.

Comment: How do you get application id? Use like this `$clietnid=(Get-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayNameStartWith MyDemoWebApp).ApplicationId`?

Comment: The application id should be like `5eea6528-b77b-4558-9425-33995e5b3dbd`?

Comment: For generation of an app ``$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "App" -HomePage "https://app.ms" -IdentifierUris "https://app.ms" -Password $secureAppPwd; $sp = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId``

Comment: For setting perms ``New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Owner -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166445/discussion-between-lukas-nespor-and-shengbao-shui-msft).