# Login to Azure powershell using Connect-AzureRmAccount in a program run in a Post publish event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, powershell, msdeploy

I have a program that uses the following code (Simplified)

```
        using (PowerShell powerInstance = PowerShell.Create()) 
        {

            powerInstance.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");


            powerInstance.AddScript("Connect-AzureRmAccount");
            powerInstance.Invoke();
        }
```

This works fine when and a login popup is shown to enter credentials.

Now I want this program to run after I publish my Web app to azure to do this I added a post publish event in my seperate web project like so

```
  <Target Name="PostAzurePublish" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
   <Exec Command="C:\MyProgram.exe"></Exec>  
  </Target>
```

The issue here is when I publish the my web App the program that runs the powershell commands runs but hangs indefinitely and the Login popup is not shown. So I am assuming it is just waiting for credentials to be supplied but beacuse the login dialog is never shown it hangs.

Is there a simple way I can get the Login dialog to show in this scenario?

Comment: `Connect-AzureRmAccount` does require credentials, yes. If you want a non-interactive login then you'll have to store credentials as securely as possible with your project and pass them to the -Credentials parameter. The cmdlet does support other ways to authenticate however: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/connect-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-6.11.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Connect-AzureRmAccount` PowerShell command without an interactive login. All you have to use is **Service Principal** for the log-in credentials.

```
$applicationId = "<service prinicple application id>";
$securePassword = "<service prinicple password>" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "<your tenantid>"
```

See my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014189/7073340)